# How to change the size of room at run time without changing its size in game maker itself?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I want to change the size of the HTML5 game when it runs on the web page without changing its original size in the game maker studio.

Comment: What you mean exactly? Is you really need change room size (variables `room_width` and `room_height`)? Or maybe you want change size of visible area?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at run-time **but not when in that same room**, so make a prep room to start the game in whose creation code sets the width and height using

```
room_set_width(room_name,width);
room_set_height(room_name,height);
room_goto_next();
```